# Accessing columns in a matrix in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple tictactoe game and am trying to save the rows to a row[] and columns to a columns[] so that I can access each element in the board by doing board[row][col].

I am getting the rows saved when traversing thru the matrix in the first loop but unable to save the column indices. Any thoughts on what im doing wrong and how to do it correctly?

Heres the code:

```
board = [ 
            ['|', '|', '|' ],
            ['|', '|', '|'],
            ['|', '|', '|'] 
        ] 

row = []
col = []

def tictactoe ():

    # print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row]) for row in board]))

    for i in range(0,len(board)):
        row.append(board[i])
        for j in (0, len(board)):
            col.append(board[j])


    print(row, '!!!!!')
    print(col)
```

Comment: Don't use `for i in range(0, len(x)):`, use `for item in x:` instead, or, if the indicies really matter, use `for i, item in enumerate(x):`

Comment: try for j in (0, len(board[i])): for second loop

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
board = [ 
            ['|', '|', '|' ],
            ['|', '|', '|'],
            ['|', '|', '|'] 
        ] 

row = []
col = []

def tictactoe ():

    # print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row]) for row in board]))

    for i in range(0,len(board)):
        row.append(board[i])
        for j in range(0, len(board[i])):
            col.append(board[i][j])


    print(row, '!!!!!')
    print(col)
```

Basically in your example you're always acessing only the items of your `board` list (i.e the rows), to access a item of a list inside the `board` list (i.e the columns), you need to access first the list inside of the `boards` array (using `board[i]`, for example), and after this you'll complete with the item you want to access, `board[i][j]`, for example.

A suggestion is, instead of using `for i in range(0, len(board))`, use directly the list iterator, as this: `for i in board`. In this case, `i` will not be an integer, but the element of the `board` variable that you're accessing. Your code will become something like this:

```
board = [ 
            ['|', '|', '|' ],
            ['|', '|', '|'],
            ['|', '|', '|'] 
        ] 

row = []
col = []

def tictactoe ():

    # print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row]) for row in board]))

    for i in board:
        row.append(i)
        for j in i:
            col.append(j)


    print(row, '!!!!!')
    print(col)
```

Note that the syntax for accessing columns change too: Instead of using `board[i][j]`, we just use `for j in i`, and the `j` variable will contains the column value itself. (as `i` is the row contained in `board` variable)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot range while iterating columns in the following line:

```
for j in (0, len(board)):
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Fernando's answer explaining what went wrong in your approach and how to solve it, here's how you can achieve the same thing in a simplified manner:

```
def tictactoe():
    rows = board # board is already an array containing the rows.
    cols = zip(*board)

    print(rows)
    print(cols)
```